# Devise Auth Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-token-auth

can anyone explain me what is the following line doing in DeviseAuthToken

```
sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false.
```

what is the function of `store: false` and `bypass: false`

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of devise-token-auth

By default DeviseTokenAuth will not check user's #active_for_authentication? which includes confirmation check on each call (it will do it only on sign in) If you want it to be validated on each request (for example, to be able to deactivate logged in users on the fly), set it to false